# Transfer data from tab bar controller to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a typical ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
override func viewDidLoad() {}
}
```

And I also have TabBarController which displays me the number of the current scene:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
  override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem!) {
    if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[0]{
      print(1)
    }
    else if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[1]{
      print(2)
    }
  }

}
```

I need my ViewController to know the number of its scene. (1 or 2). How can I deliver him this number for use from TabBarController?

Comment: Is `ViewController` a child of `TabBarController` ?

Comment: You should not be subclassing UITabBarController just to learn that an item was selected. Instead, use the tab bar controller's _delegate_. If your view controller _is_ the delegate, presto, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is, add a property called `number`, or whatever you like, to your `ViewController` class.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var number: Int!
}
```

Then in tabBarController's `viewDidLoad`, loop through the view controllers, check if they are of type `ViewController`, and then set their `number` property to the index of the tabBarController's view controllers:

```swift
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for (index,vc) in (viewControllers!.enumerated())! {
      if let viewController = vc as? ViewController {
        vc.number = index
      }
    }
  }

  override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem!) {
    if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[0]{
      print(1)
    }
    else if item == (self.tabBar.items as! [UITabBarItem])[1]{
      print(2)
    }
  }

}
```

Unless, are you wanting to set the value whenever the tab is selected?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The solution solves the problem. But there is a small question: Why when I try to call the view controller function from the tabbar view, is it called twice?

Comment: Hmm, the code I provided only assigns the `number` property. If something is being called twice, it isn't likely due to the code I provided. Can you provide some code as to how you're actually using this `number` property? Are you using an `IBAction`?